# Pin control bar in ubuntu teams app

Tags: 20.04, software-center, update-manager, system-settings, microsoft-teams

I have installed Microsoft Teams Version 1.3.00.30857 (64-bit) through Software app in Ubuntu. But I find this bar not pinned at top as I saw in windows.
[I want this position of control bar in teams](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JdKQ.png)

[What I am having currently after recently installing teams app in Ubuntu LTS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewtwP.png)

I clicked "check for updates" in teams app but it had prompted this "Please go to the package manager to check for Teams updates."
So I opened Software app in ubuntu and opened this and found this
[Saw this in Software app in ubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9E1tq.png)
Further after opening wifi settings as prompted, I found that metered connection is already turned off!
[Metered connection already off!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Al5h.png)
Please help me with this. I want to get the app fully updated and see control bar pinned.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS, installed 3 days ago!

Comment: Unfortunately Teams on Linux is not necessarily the same as Teams on Windows. You can expect Windows users to have features we do not have, though the core functionality should be there (ie it is usable).